# WSO2 Endpoint look-up sample

Tags: wso2, sample, wso2-governance-registry

I am trying to set up the WSO2 Endpoint look-up sample. I have made the changes according to the documentation, but when I try to build the app using "mvn clean install" I am receiving the following error:

```
Downloading: http://maven.wso2.org/nexus/content/groups/wso2-public/eclipse/vali
dateutility/0.95/validateutility-0.95.pom
[WARNING] Checksum validation failed, expected 53f8bac71524372a3d51a6ecf11365042
96f37af but is 8edc83998e0bf2a8867395883f3853eb901be267 for http://maven.wso2.or
g/nexus/content/groups/wso2-public/eclipse/validateutility/0.95/validateutility-
0.95.pom
Downloading: http://maven.wso2.org/nexus/content/groups/wso2-public/org/eclipse/
osgi/org.eclipse.osgi.services/3.2.0.v20090520-1800/org.eclipse.osgi.services-3.
2.0.v20090520-1800.pom
[WARNING] Checksum validation failed, expected <!DOCTYPE but is 8edc83998e0bf2a8
867395883f3853eb901be267 for http://maven.wso2.org/nexus/content/groups/wso2-pub
lic/org/eclipse/osgi/org.eclipse.osgi.services/3.2.0.v20090520-1800/org.eclipse.
osgi.services-3.2.0.v20090520-1800.pom
```

The checksums are failing. Does someone need to update the files in the repository?

Comment: which product are you using (e.g. ESB, Governance Registry)?  what is the version of the product you are trying?

Comment: I am using Governance Registry v4.5.3

Comment: The validateutility-0.95.pom file has 2011 as a year and the md5 and sha1 files have 2013. The org.eclipse.osgi.services-3.
2.0.v20090520-1800.pom has a year of 2011 but the sha1 has 2010.

Comment: I've just tried and I have received the same error as you.  It may be worth you creating a [JIRA issue](https://wso2.org/jira/secure/Dashboard.jspa), athough I wouldn't expect a quick resolution. I have a JIRA for a similar maven repo issue [BRS-24](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/BRS-24) on BRS that I opened in Oct 2012.  If you need to resolve this urgently, maybe you could try building GREG from source?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get the handler sample to build by:

1) Checkout the Greg 4.5.3 Source Code:

`svn co https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/tags/4.0.5/products/greg/4.5.3/ wso2_greg_453`

2) Build the source:

```
cd wso2_greg_453
mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true
```

I had a build failure due to maven issues cleaning up surefire reports, which I ignored.

3) Build the handler sample in the directory I unzipped the binary version of GREG to:

```
cd %CARBON_HOME%
wso2greg-4.5.3\samples\handler\src
mvn clean install
```

This time the handler sample built ok.

The approach above is a bit long winded, but it works!