# WSO2 Greg 4.5 and 3.0 diffrence, gadgets missing

Tags: registry, wso2, wso2-governance-registry

I am trying to demonstrate run-time governance on a set of services by providing service matrices(service usage etc), but looks like the supporting gadgets in **[ver 3.0](http://wso2.com/library/articles/soa-governance-wso2-registry-v1-1/#Dashboard)** are not there in the latest **[version 4.5](http://docs.wso2.org/display/Governance411/The+Built-in+Gadgets)** .

Can someone please suggest on how to acheive this and  point out if my inference is wrong?

Thanks,
Wajid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes the gadgets that were shipped with version 3.0 are not shipped with newer versions. to achieve proper monitoring governance registry needs to be integrated with WSO2 BAM [1].This documentation should be helpful in understanding this [2].

[1] http://wso2.com/products/business-activity-monitor

[2] http://docs.wso2.org/display/Governance450/Statistics+Collector+Sample

Regards,
Pulasthi

Comment: Thanks a lot for responding. I have been trying to build some samples to do so but have been encountering build issues that required me to take a checkout of the complete source.                                            Can you please validate if the solution listed here that requires a complete source code checkout is the suggested option.       http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17225381/wso2-endpoint-look-up-sample

Comment: AFAIK the samples that are shipped with the binaries should work properly is you are coming across build errors the solution suggested in the other thread should also work

Comment: Well the samples worked but i had to re-create the binaries from the source post the checkout..as was listed in the other thread   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17225381/wso2-endpoint-look-up-sample.. that makes the product difficult to sell :-) .. thanks for spending ur time on this..